# How to divide a dataset into multiple datasets based on values in a specific column in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, split, dataset, filtering

I have a dataset (see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5NukgjqgEa0zXoL_VIWZde3PsesYXtURTQjk1KyTzY/edit?usp=sharing)) in which data are available for multiple countries in a period of time that its starting year is unknown (the starting point for each country is different), but we know that last year is 2016. I need to split this dataset into multiple datasets based on the "year" column in a way that gives me a dataset for each year with data for all countries.

I have tried this:

```
efyear = dict(tuple(eef.groupby('year')))

y = 2016
for y in eef['year']:
    try:
        exec(f'ef{y} = efyear{y}')
        y -= 1
    except:
        print('Not Available')
```

but it doesn't work and ends up with 'Not Available' printed many times. I need to produce different names for each dataset or the variable that hold that dataset that was why I used formatting.

Thank you in advance.

You can see the dataset [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E5NukgjqgEa0zXoL_VIWZde3PsesYXtURTQjk1KyTzY/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: `[v for k, v in df.groupby('year')]`

Comment: @AnuragDabas Thank you for the suggestion but it was not what I looking for. I have updated my question. could you please review it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
out = {}
for year, g in df.groupby("year"):
    out["ef{}".format(year)] = g

print(out)
```

This will create a dictionary with keys `ef2013`, `ef2014` etc. and values are dataframes for the year.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer :))

```
efyear = dict(tuple(eef.groupby('year')))
y = 2016
for y in eef['year']:
    exec(f'ef{y} = efyear[{y}]')
    y -= 1
```

:))